# Words to seed translation

Tags: wallet, paper-wallet, mnemonic-seed, seed

In bitcoin wallet that support *bip39* mnemonic code, is there a way to get the 12/24 words from the seed generated by them?
Or the translation is one-way only (from words to seed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to convert the resulting seed back to the original mnemonic.

As stated in the [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) proposal:

> To create a binary seed from the mnemonic, we use the PBKDF2 function
>   with a mnemonic sentence (in UTF-8 NFKD) used as the password and the
>   string "mnemonic" + passphrase (again in UTF-8 NFKD) used as the salt.

The seed (and optional passphrase) are passed through pbkdf2, which is not reversible.